# Trigger action on focus but only when it's not because of a click

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I run some JS code when I tab over to a link, but not when I click on it?

The code I want to run is some scrolling. See below...

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a')

links.forEach(function (link) {
  link.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
    // if (focus caused by click) return 'Don't do anything.'
    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop
    var y = link.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollTop
    return window.scroll({top: y - 20, behavior: 'smooth'})
  })
})
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

div {
  height: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#1">One</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#2">Two</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#3">Three</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<div>Some More Space</div>
```

Point being, when the user clicks on the link, I just want to abort the scrolling and just visit the link (the actual default behavior). Instead I get scrolls but no link behavior. I have to click again to activate the link : (

Comment: `focus` will fire just after the Client clicks an input and it receives focus. So, you would not know if the Client tabbed into the Element, or it was clicked. Maybe, you really want to set a variable onblur of your other Elements, and have click Events clear the variable you test for onfocus.

Comment: The click events are just normal clicking of links. Should I grab and override every link click?

Answer (score 1):

Click doesn't happen until the Client releases the mouse, so I had to use `touchstart` on mobile and `mousedown` on desktop.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, html, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(typeof FormData !== 'undefined' && send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      let s, r = [];
      for(let p in send){
        s = send[p];
        if(typeof s === 'object')s = JSON.stringify(s);
        r.push(encodeURIComponent(p)+'='+encodeURIComponent(s));
      }
      x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); x.send(r.join('&'));
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
// you can put the below on another page in a load Event - besides the end load and below
const inputs = Q('#inputs>input');
let yup = true;
function falseYup(){
  yup = false;
}
for(let n of inputs){
  if(mobile){
    n.ontouchstart = falseYup;
  }
  else{
    n.onmousedown = falseYup;
  }
  n.onfocus = ()=>{ 
    console.clear(); console.log(yup); // test for yup here then set to true later
    yup = true;
  }
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.main{
  padding:10px;
}
label,input[type=text]{
  width:100%; font:bold 22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
input[type=text]{
  width:100%; padding:3px 5px; margin-bottom:7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='inputs'>
      <label for='input1'>Input 1</label><input id='input1' type='text' value='' />
      <label for='input2'>Input 2</label><input id='input2' type='text' value='' />
      <label for='input3'>Input 3</label><input id='input3' type='text' value='' />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! So... the reason I'm messing around with tabs is because I have a sticky header on my site, and tabbing through links sometimes places them behind the header, making them not visible. Maybe there's just a better way to fix that than grabbing all the links and adding scrolling code via focus events.

Comment: If you set the HTML Element [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute to `'-1'` it will stop tab focus. If that is all you wanted, you should have made your question more clear.

Comment: I don't want to stop tab focus; it's useful. It's just if I tab through the links in my site, they're focused behind my sticky header (where you can't tell they're in focus). The approach I was taking to solving that is grabbing all the links and implementing a scroll on focus, but now clicking on links moves them before mouseup happens and links aren't clickable. Thus the problem of not scrolling when the focus is cause by a mousedown. Make sense?

Comment: Adjusted the question here as per your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840681/default-tabbing-behavior-puts-links-behind-sticky-header