# Default tabbing behavior puts links behind sticky header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sticky header on my site. I also have focus styles on links. When a user tabs through the links on the website (especially backwards by pressing shift + tab), sometimes those focused links are behind the sticky header, and the user can't see what is focused.

I tried to solve this by adding my own listeners on 'focus' to scroll the links into the viewport. All good, except now when I click on a link, the mousedown changes the focus, initiates the scroll, and the mouseup happens after the link has moved, meaning.... the click event never fires on these links and they don't go anywhere : (

How can I solve this?

Code without the JS I added. Try tabbing through the links backwards and watch them disappear:

```css
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: .5em 0;
}

div {
  height: 135px;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>Fancy Title</header>
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#1">One</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#2">Two</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#3">Three</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<div>Some More Space</div>
```

And here's with the scrolling, but now clicking is broken:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a')

links.forEach(function (link) {
  link.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
    // if (focus caused by click) return 'Don't do anything.'
    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop
    var y = link.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollTop - 52
    return window.scroll({top: y - 20, behavior: 'smooth'})
  })
})


// Just to demonstrate that the clicks don't happen

links.forEach(function (link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    link.style.background = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
  })
})
```

```css
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: .5em 0;
}

div {
  height: 135px;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>Fancy Title</header>
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#1">One</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#2">Two</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<a href="#3">Three</a>
<div>Some Space</div>
<div>Some More Space</div>
```

Comment: PS: I love web dev. So many fun adventures you never saw coming...

Comment: Could you please add the missing header to have an overview of your issue?

Comment: the issue is that a click is mousedown/mouseup .. when you mouseup you will trigger the focus and the element will move and you cannot mouseup so no click. If you click faster it will work

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Telling users to click faster isn’t a solution, though.

Comment: @Ry- I am explaining why it's happening because for sure many people will notice that it's working fine half the cases. It wasn't really a solution but since I am not good at JS it can probably help finding the solution (like waiting for the mouseup before running the animation)

Comment: It’s weird that I’ve never had to solve problem before :D It seems like it should be relevant any time a sticky header is involved. Moving `<html>` (or another container) down might work? Or it might require making that moved element scrolling, which is bad on mobile.

Comment: Aha, https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-padding/. (No IE11 support.)

Comment: Could you put the scrollable content in a wrapper div, with padding or margin top the same height as the sticky header, so content could never float behind the header?

Comment: Hahahaaa! This is the best comment stream. I put the sticker header in, but it kinda distorts the problem. The problem isn't that I'm not programmatically scrolling the right amount, it's that if I didn't have the JavaScript in there it would hide the links on shift + tab (reverse scrolling). Maybe I can insert two code snippets...? Yeup, two snippets now. One without any JS (hidden links), one with JS for scrolling, (clicking doesn't work).

Comment: WAIT! I think I thought of a solution.... If I only initiate any scrolling at all when the item isn't in the viewport, then clicking on links in the viewport won't scroll, and you can't click links out of the viewport so no problems there, and it's the ones out of the viewport that need the scrolling anyway.... Check my crazy math, would this work?