# How to select all html elements the user can tab over to with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

How can I select all the elements that a user can press tab to navigate to?

Do I have to hard code for input, textarea, a, button, and so on, or is there a way to identify them via the browser's default?

What I am ultimately trying to accomplish is here: [Default tabbing behavior puts links behind sticky header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840681/default-tabbing-behavior-puts-links-behind-sticky-header?noredirect=1#comment107643212_60840681)

Comment: Can you try using a selector like document.querySelectorAll("[tab-index]")? Having tab-index attribute as a non negative value assures that it is focus by the tab.

Comment: I'd have to manually add the attribute to all my elements, but then that's not a bad thing to have control over anyhow... right?

Comment: not bad though... but for making elements to be navigable using tab key, we need to add "tabIndex" attribute, otherwise other than default accessible elements like (a, button, input etc) other elements won't be navigable.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function that queries for every element that is *focusable* and filter out those that are disabled, because that disables the focus.

```
const getKeyboardFocusableElements = (element = document) =>
  Array.from(element.querySelectorAll(
    'a, button, input, textarea, select, details,[tabindex]:not([tabindex="-1"])'
  )).filter(el => !el.hasAttribute('disabled'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using a selector like `document.querySelectorAll("[tab-index]")`?

As having tab-index attribute as a non negative value assures that it is focus by the tab